# Sometimes I get (Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined)

Tags: jquery

Sometime I get the following error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
```

but then without changing anything, I will not get the error, then after a while the error will start showing up again.

Is this a server issue, of how the files are getting served?  Or is there something in my code I can change to avoid this?

Comment: It could be a number of different issues. Inspect the resources using your browser's console to see whether or not jQuery loaded. It could be a timing issue or a server issue. More likely that it is a timing issue.

Comment: Show your code please

Comment: put your jquery script reference as the first script ref at the head part of html

Comment: Look at the console. There probably was a problem fetching the jquery file.

Comment: @dystroy the console is where I get that error, I went ahead and moved my jquery to the top of any file.  So I will see if it that fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably get that error after clearing your cache when your browser has to reload that file. You might be trying to use the jQuery operator `$` before jQuery gets loaded. Make sure jQuery is loaded before anything that uses it.